# Ruby / Rails: why isn't 'update_attribute' named with a bang ("!")?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, naming-conventions

Given that `update_attribute` mutates the object and saves to the database, why isn't it named with a bang? My only guess is that methods touching the db tend to be named if they raise an exception upon failure instead of just returning false, but I'm not sure that's what's driving the naming scheme.

Comment: Didn't you just ask this same question?

Comment: @BradWerth My original question wasn't specific enough. I already know about the 'safe'/'dangerous' (mutating) naming convention as concerns "!", but I'm confused why `update_attribute` seems to defy that very convention.

Comment: Check out that link in your other question. This is totally opinion, anyway. I will repeat: From matz in linked question: "The bang sign means 'the bang version is more dangerous than its non bang counterpart; handle with care'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Brad Werth said, Ruby intends that a method with a `!` at the end should have another similarly named method without the `!` at the end. The version with the`!` should be the dangerous version. If you have a method with a `!` at the end but not a non-bang counterpart then that is what's known as a prima-donna method and is a code smell. See, for example: https://github.com/troessner/reek/wiki/Prima-Donna-Method.

The reason `update_attribute` doesn't have a `!` at the end has nothing to do with whether it mutates data in the database or whether it raises an exception or not. It's simply because mutating data in the database is the normal function for the `update_attribute` method. And there is no bang counterpart because there isn't a "dangerous" version of it. The convention that `!` raises an exception was arbitrary at the time, but makes sense for how ActiveRecird uses `save!`. But that doesn't make `!` = "raises an exception" a rule.